# Overwrite previously printed lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, command-line-interface

I am writing a package that will allow the user to select an option.
ie.

```py
print("What is your favourite singer?")
print("Sia")
print("> Rachel Platten")
print("Parade Of Lights")
```

In this case "Rachel Platten" is selected singer, but when the user presses "up" key, I want to rewrite the text in stdout to show Sia as a selected singer.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've found a way to solve this.
To flush/erase x previously written lines to stdout:

```py
ERASE_LINE = "\x1b[2K"

for i in range(1, x):
    print(f"\x1b[{i}A{ERASE_LINE}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in python3 :

```
import time

for x in range(25):
    print(f'\r This is loop: {x}', end='')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

The `\r` in the f-string clears the last line before displaying the new print and I'm not sure what the `end=''` does, but without it, it won't work.

Comment: Nope, this works if you want to edit the previous line, but I want to edit the last X printed lines in terminal.